# Javascript Lingo game - String char equal to another string char

Tags: javascript, html

Wat i am trying to do is that if checkW string has a letter that is in the checkR than i want this letter to apear as var length = random.length; document.write(Array(length).join("?")); but instead of ? at the letters place it has to show that letter until the whole word is found.

Example: if i type endu and the country that has randomly been choose is Nederland that i want to output this nede???nd because we only found this letters in the string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Lingo spel</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Lingo spel voor de eu landen en hoofdsteden.">
        <meta name="Author" content="Ronald Julian Dewindt">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
            <h3>Lingo spel - Eu landen en hoofdsteden</h3>
            <label>Typ een woord in:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" id="woord">
            <button type="button" onclick="lingo()">Check</button>
            <br><br>
            <p><b>Woorden geprobeerd!</b></p>
            <p id="try">-----</p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var euLanden = new Array('Nederlands','Duitsland','Zweden');
            var random =   euLanden[Math.floor(Math.random() * euLanden.length)]; 
            var random =   random.toLowerCase();
            var woordenG=  new Array();

            function lingo()
            {
                var woord = document.getElementById("woord").value;
                var woord = woord.toLowerCase();
                if(woord == "")
                    {
                        alert("U bent vergeten een woord in te typen!");
                        return;
                    }
                woordenG.push(woord);
                document.getElementById("try").innerHTML=woordenG;

                var checkW = woord.split('');
                var checkR = random.split('');

                alert(checkW);
                for(i=0; i<checkW.length; i++) //starts at 0++
                    {
                        alert(checkW[i]);
                        /*if(checkW[i] == checkR)
                            {
                                alert("Its working");
                            }*/
                    }
            }
        </script>
        <p id="hidden"><script>
            var length = random.length; document.write(Array(length).join("?"));
                       </script></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterate over all letters in the country name and check if they are present somewhere in the user's "input". if so, append them to the result, if not, append a question mark to the result:

```
function mask(countryName, textInput)
{
  var output = "";
  for(var i=0; i < countryName.length; i++)
  {
     if(textInput.contains(countryName[i]))
     {
        output += countryName[i];
     }
     else
     {
        output += "?";
     }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Example :

```
> mask("nederland", "endu")
< "nede???nd"
```

note : your example in the question is somewhat flawed ; if the word in Lingo is `"Nederland"`, and the letters `"ENDU"` have been guessed, output should be `"nede???nd"`, rather than `"nede?????"`

Comment: How can i replace .contains() with the .indexOf() or .search()

Comment: .indexOf() will return -1 if the passed string is not found. ( `var a = "a"; alert(a.indexOf("b")` will alert `-1`)

Comment: Search will do the exact same thing btw

Comment: Sorry, het is een beetje lastig te volgen wat je precies wil doen zo :P probeer het eens in het Nederlands?